# Multi-targeted NuGet package won't build: System.Linq & System.Data.SqlDataClient packages not importing on the build server?

Tags: .net, .net-core, build, nuget-package-restore

We are building a NuGet package that targets all versions of .NET Framework from 4.5 through 4.8, and .NET Standard 2.0 and 2.1. The .csproj file uses the new format, and specifies the target frameworks as follows:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net45;net451;net452;net46;net461;net462;net47;net471;net472;net48;netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1;</TargetFrameworks>
```

We used NuGet Package Manager to add references to both `System.Data.SqlClient` and `System.Linq` to the project. It added all the `PackageReference` nodes to the project file and they appear to be correct, as shown in **Package References**, below.

This builds correctly when compiling locally. A folder is created for each version of the target framework, and assemblies are output in each folder.

However, when we attempt to build the package on the build server (using a YAML pipeline in Azure DevOps which has historically worked for all our other NuGet packages), the build fails with the errors given in **Build Log Messages**, below. These messages (`IEnumerable.Take` and `SqlDateTime` being unresolved) appear on the .NET 4.5 build; all other versions report that `String`, `Object`, and `Void` are not defined.

We've tried removing and adding the package references by hand, and with NuGet Package Manager, but there is no difference. We cannot determine why these references will not resolve on the build server.

Each class does have an explicit `using` statement at the top of the file.

FWIW, the build pipeline is using the `VSBuild@1` task to build the project. We don't get past the build for packing to be an issue.

**THE QUESTION:** What could be causing this issue, and how do we resolve it?

### Package References

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
   <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient">
     <Version>4.8.3</Version>
   </PackageReference>
   <Reference Include="netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51">
      <Private>true</Private>
   </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.1'">
   <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient">
     <Version>4.8.3</Version>
   </PackageReference>
   <Reference Include="netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51">
      <Private>true</Private>
   </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net451'">
  <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient">
    <Version>4.8.3</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452'">
  <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient">
    <Version>4.8.3</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net46'">
  <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient">
    <Version>4.8.3</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461'">
  <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient">
    <Version>4.8.3</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net462'">
  <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient">
    <Version>4.8.3</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net47'">
  <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient">
    <Version>4.8.3</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net471'">
  <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient">
    <Version>4.8.3</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net472'">
  <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient">
    <Version>4.8.3</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net48'">
  <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient">
    <Version>4.8.3</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="OCCM.PT.Exception" Version="1.0.8" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

### Build Log Messages

```
##[error]FileValidator.cs(115,25): Error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs;linenumber=115;columnnumber=25;code=CS1061;]'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs(115,25): error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\OCCM.PT.Validation.csproj]
##[error]FileValidator.cs(122,23): Error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs;linenumber=122;columnnumber=23;code=CS1061;]'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs(122,23): error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\OCCM.PT.Validation.csproj]
##[error]FileValidator.cs(123,25): Error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs;linenumber=123;columnnumber=25;code=CS1061;]'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs(123,25): error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\OCCM.PT.Validation.csproj]
##[error]FileValidator.cs(124,25): Error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs;linenumber=124;columnnumber=25;code=CS1061;]'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs(124,25): error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\OCCM.PT.Validation.csproj]
##[error]FileValidator.cs(125,25): Error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs;linenumber=125;columnnumber=25;code=CS1061;]'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs(125,25): error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\OCCM.PT.Validation.csproj]
##[error]FileValidator.cs(126,25): Error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs;linenumber=126;columnnumber=25;code=CS1061;]'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs(126,25): error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\OCCM.PT.Validation.csproj]
##[error]FileValidator.cs(127,25): Error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs;linenumber=127;columnnumber=25;code=CS1061;]'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs(127,25): error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\OCCM.PT.Validation.csproj]
##[error]FileValidator.cs(134,23): Error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs;linenumber=134;columnnumber=23;code=CS1061;]'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\FileValidator.cs(134,23): error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\OCCM.PT.Validation.csproj]
##[error]Validator.cs(129,19): Error CS0103: The name 'SqlDateTime' does not exist in the current context
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\Validator.cs;linenumber=129;columnnumber=19;code=CS0103;]The name 'SqlDateTime' does not exist in the current context
D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\Validator.cs(129,19): error CS0103: The name 'SqlDateTime' does not exist in the current context [D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\OCCM.PT.Validation.csproj]
##[error]Validator.cs(130,85): Error CS0103: The name 'SqlDateTime' does not exist in the current context
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\Validator.cs;linenumber=130;columnnumber=85;code=CS0103;]The name 'SqlDateTime' does not exist in the current context
D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\Validator.cs(130,85): error CS0103: The name 'SqlDateTime' does not exist in the current context [D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\OCCM.PT.Validation.csproj]
##[error]Validator.cs(132,19): Error CS0103: The name 'SqlDateTime' does not exist in the current context
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\Validator.cs;linenumber=132;columnnumber=19;code=CS0103;]The name 'SqlDateTime' does not exist in the current context
D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\Validator.cs(132,19): error CS0103: The name 'SqlDateTime' does not exist in the current context [D:\azagent\A2\_work\1564\s\OCCM.PT.Validation.csproj]
##[error]Validator.cs(133,88): Error CS0103: The name 'SqlDateTime' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: Have you done a Nuget Restore before the build on the Azure machine?

Comment: Yes. It's built into the build pipeline. We use the `NuGetCommand@2` task to restore packages immediately prior to executing the `VSBuild@1` task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In perusing the available documentation, I eventually found a paragraph in Microsoft's article on [Cross-Platform Targeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting) that led me to a solution:

> AVOID multi-targeting as well as targeting .NET Standard, if your source code is the same for all targets.
>
> The .NET Standard assembly will automatically be used by NuGet. Targeting individual .NET implementations increases the *.nupkg size for no benefit.

"Avoid" is a curious choice of words here, since it appears that targeting .NET 4.5 through 4.8 **and** .NET Standard was the culprit. When I removed all support for .NET Framework 4.5 through .NET 4.8, the solution built as expected in DevOps.

Interestingly, in the same article, Microsoft advises the following:

> CONSIDER adding a target for net461 when you're offering a netstandard2.0 target.
>
> Using .NET Standard 2.0 from .NET Framework has some issues that were addressed in .NET Framework 4.7.2. You can improve the experience for developers that are still on .NET Framework 4.6.1 - 4.7.1 by offering them a binary that is built for .NET Framework 4.6.1.

However, when I did so, the 4.6.1 build broke in spectacular ways, particularly when it tried to compile AssemblyInfo.cs (a file which is apparently dynamically generated). None of the primitive types in that file (`object`, `string`, `int`, `DateTime`, etc.) were available. If anyone has any insight into this, I'd be very interested into the cause and possible solutions.

However, my issue is resolved, and I am happy to report that I believe I know what was happening and how to prevent it from occurring in the future. (Don't mix .NET platforms in the project file.)